# prevent EOL character from being changed when reading/writing from/to a csv file

Tags: python, macos, csv

I'm using the csv module in Python 3.8 to read and modify data in .csv files on macOS.
Python seems to change all of the EOL characters in my original .csv files.

This behaviour is not desired, because it makes it impossible for me to keep track of data changes.
All of the lines have '^M' appended to them, (which is '\r', a.k.a. the carriage return character).
The result is that, in Git, all of the lines are marked as changed.

When reading the original .csv file in binary mode, Python tells me that original EOL character is '\r\n'.

So I try to use this EOL character when writing to .csv:

```
def file_to_rows(path):
  rows = []
  with open(path) as csv_file:
    row_reader = csv.reader(
      csv_file, 
      delimiter=';',
      quotechar='|',
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in row_reader:
        rows.append(row)
  return rows

def rows_to_file(rows, path):
  with open(path, 'w', endline='\r\n') as csvfile:
    rowswriter = csv.writer(
      csvfile, 
      delimiter=';',
      quotechar='|',
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in rows:
      rowswriter.writerow(row)

# Running this function on a file should show NO changes in Git.
def csv_pass_through(path):
  rows = file_to_rows(path)
  rows_to_file(rows, path)
```

But `git diff` still shows me an '^M' has been added to all lines.
So it seems like Python is adding one carriage return character too many.

So, how does one read/write .csv data transparently (i.e. WITHOUT implicitly changing anything)?

Comment: I believe standard CSV formatted file are terminated with `'\r\n'` (at least the the default in the `csv` module). You may be able to override that by specifying a `lineterminator='\r'` (or whatever) when you create the `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

martineau's comment was right. You can override the default '\r\n' in the writer constructor, like so:

```
def rows_to_file(rows, path):
  with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
    rowswriter = csv.writer(
      csvfile, 
      delimiter=';',
      lineterminator='\n',
      quotechar='|',
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in rows:
      rowswriter.writerow(row)
```